# Run the Update sql Script on Existing Database using WIX Installer during Upgrade

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I am creating installer for Creating the databaase using WIX. But I could not able to find a way to run the udate script during Upgrade.

Code for Create DB

```
<Directory Id="DFDB" Name="DealFoundryDataBase" FileSource="$(var.SolutionDir)DealFoundrySetup/DataBaseScripts">
          <Component Id='SqlComponent_Files' Guid='{07DB58E6-5AFC-4BB0-84EC-C5EC6B0E5CA7}' KeyPath='yes'>
            <File Id="CreateTable_sql" Name="CreateTable.sql"/>
            <File Id="InsertStatements_sql" Name="InsertStatements.sql"/>
            <File Id="DFCoreScript_sql" Name="DFCoreScript.sql"/>
          </Component>

            <Component Id='SqlComponent' Guid='{C5412828-84FB-4CC5-AC71-AC246B9D09E8}' KeyPath='yes'>
              <Condition><![CDATA[NOT OLDER_VERSION_FOUND]]> </Condition>
              <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='[PRO_DFDATABASE_NAME]' User='SQLUser' Server='[PRO_DFDATABASE_SOURCE]'
                CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='yes' ContinueOnError='yes'>
                <sql:SqlScript Id='CreateTable' BinaryKey='CreateTable' ExecuteOnInstall='yes' />
                <!--<sql:SqlScript Id='InsertStatements' BinaryKey='InsertStatements' ExecuteOnInstall='yes'/>-->
              </sql:SqlDatabase>
            </Component>



        </Directory>

 <Binary Id ='CreateTable' SourceFile='$(var.SolutionDir)DealFoundrySetup/DataBaseScripts/DFCoreScript.sql'/>
    <Binary Id ='InsertStatements' SourceFile='$(var.SolutionDir)DealFoundrySetup/DataBaseScripts/InsertStatements.sql'/>
    <Binary Id ='MasterData' SourceFile='$(var.SolutionDir)DealFoundrySetup/DataBaseScripts/MasterData.sql'/>
    <util:User Id='SQLUser' Name='[PRO_DFDATABASE_USERID]' Password='[PRO_DFDATABASE_PASSWORD]' />
```

The above lines of code is working fine for creting the DB on Install, but I want to run the update script during upgrade on Existing DB
Plz Help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh... Versioning.  So much fun.

First, make sure you have your  tags set in the installer.  Here is what I usually do (and this is rather complicated because you might want to check for specific versions to do different upgrade scripts):

```
<Upgrade Id="{YOUR GUID HERE}" > <!--never change me-->
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Minimum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="NEWERPRODUCTFOUND" IncludeMinimum="no" />
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Minimum="5.0.0" Maximum="$(var.ProductVersion)" Property="OLDERVERSIONBEINGUPGRADED" IncludeMaximum="no" RemoveFeatures="All" />
  <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="yes" Maximum="5.0.0 " Property="VERYOLDVERSIONFOUND" IncludeMaximum="no" />
</Upgrade>
```

You can have as many of these "versions" defined as you want, and maybe each one will run a different upgrade script for your database.  They will set the properties defined in this list.

Secondly, WiX defines a well known value 'Installed' that is only used when you are doing an uninstall or upgrade:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa369297.aspx

So if you wish to only run it *ONLY* while doing an upgrade, you should use this:

```
  <Condition><![CDATA[NOT Installed OR NOT VERYOLDVERSIONFOUND]]> </Condition>
```

If you want to run it if you are doing an upgrade or installing, it should be this way:

```
  <Condition><![CDATA[(NOT Installed AND Installed) OR (NOT VERYOLDVERSIONFOUND AND VERYOLDVERSIONFOUND]]> </Condition>
```

Which is the same as not having a condition at all since it will always be true.